# Is DOMContentLoaded event EXACTLY the same as jQuery's .ready() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, dom-events

I have replaced `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {});` with jQuery's `$(document).bind('ready', function() {});`, because first one failed to work on IE < 9 and I did not wanted to play with `.attachEvent()` for that dummy browser, if I could have this nicely covered by jQuery itself.

Shortly after replacement, I noticed that `DOMContentLoaded` event was always fired around 0-2 miliseconds after page load / refresh (at least this is what was logged by my logging script), while `.ready()` always requires at least 15-20 miliseconds, after page refresh, to be fired (again - as logged by script).

I'm asking purely for feeding my curiosity, why there is such "significant" delay? Of course, there is no problem for me, that jQuery is firing that event later. It is just, that because I want to know ALL the answers (and rule the world! :]), I can't sleep with that! :]

**EDIT**: in [.ready() function doc](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) some user (Nick (of Nexxar)) points out that: "*jQuery simulates the non existing "DOMContentLoaded" event on IE, but the used mechanism fires much later than the event used on other browsers*". Maybe this is the same, I'm asking for?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming browser that supports the event:

1. The real event can support any `document`. jQuery will only use the `document` it was loaded in, no matter what you pass to it.
2. jQuery will fire the event asynchronously even if the event has already happened. Attaching `'DOMContentLoaded'` event will do nothing if the event has already happened.

There is no delay in these browsers, see http://jsfiddle.net/rqTAX/3/ (the offsets logged are in milliseconds).

For browsers that don't support the event, jQuery's will obviously work for them as well. It will use a hacky mechanism that is not the same as the real `DOMContentLoaded` and will not necessarily fire as soon as the real `DOMContentLoaded` would:

```
// The DOM ready check for Internet Explorer
function doScrollCheck() {
    if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        // If IE is used, use the trick by Diego Perini
        // http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/
        document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
    } catch(e) {
        setTimeout( doScrollCheck, 1 );
        return;
    }

    // and execute any waiting functions
    jQuery.ready();
}
```

Comment: If I'm not getting you wrong, your answer only explains, why there could be a delay (change of time, when event is fired) in browsers that DOESN'T support `DOMContentLoaded` (like IE < 9). But I tested the thing in a browser that surely supports it (Chrome 20 and Firefox 13) and got delays of around 15-20 seconds in both browsers.

Comment: @trejder sorry I am not seeing anything like that whatsoever. See http://jsfiddle.net/rqTAX/3/. The differences are like 5-20 milliseconds. In chrome and firefox

Comment: No need to sorry! :] It was purely my curiosity. Maybe I missed something. I think, we can close this topic, as for me. Thanks!

Comment: @trejder well you could at least accept my answer for providing the 2 differences at top that most people don't know about ;) Btw, you should use `$(document).ready` instead of `.bind`, they are very different.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, as I was `sure` I did accepted your answer! :] Sorry! BTW: Why `$(document).bind('ready', function() {});` and `$(document).ready(function() {});` are so different?

Comment: @trejder the `.bind` version won't get jQuery as first argument to the function and also won't work after the DOMContentLoaded has happened. So you lose these advantages. It is also very uncommon, this is the first time I see it.

Comment: Well... In, for example, `.load()` [method description](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) there is an information: "_This method is a shortcut for `.bind('load', handler)`._". So, I assumed that the same relation goes here. That `.ready(handler)` is just a shortcut for `.bind('ready', handler)`.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery simulates this event by binding to the `document`'s `readystatechange` event, which is the standard way of simulating `DOMContentLoaded` in oldIE.

[According to the jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L847), that event fires "late" but before `window.onload`. However, I can't find *when* that event fires exactly. `DOMContentLoaded` fires when the DOM is built and ready for scripting, so `readystatechange` fires *after* that; perhaps it waits for layout rendering or styling something like that, or the event is triggered later in the rendering/layout process?

Regardless, it will likely fire *after* `DOMContentLoaded`, likely due to when IE decides to update the `document`'s `readyState` to "complete."

(If anyone has a definite answer, post a comment and I'll update this answer; I'd love to know when exactly it fires myself, and I can't find that answer in any documentation or on any sites I would expect like Quirksmode.)

Comment: OK, but similar like above. You're mostly talking about IE. And the very same delays happens in both newest Chrome and newest Firefox.

Comment: DOMContentLoaded happens AFTER scripts (regular and `defer`ed) are run (except `async` ones)

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for the 'ready' appearing to fire later (in practice) is that there may be many events hooked up to it. If any of these are long running synchronous operations then the ready event will come much later. For instance I use knockout.js and it can take 500ms to initialize the page.

---

However using your minimal test page that isn't the case of course. I tried running the following :

```
 console.log(window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd -
             window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart);
```

This gives about 6ms even for your simple super page

---

Also I took your code and ran it through Chrome's performance tools and discovered a few interesting things:

[image]

- BTW: The vertical blue bar is DOMCONTENTLOADED and the green is 'first paint'
- You can see even just a super simple function call on the DOMCONTENTLOADED event can take 5ms (and this is on an i7). Remember it needs to be parsed and things need initializing.
- The callbacks are shown in the cyan color (anonymous), the first is from the DOMCONTENTLOADED event and the second is the 'ready' callback.
- You will notice 'Timer Fired' (i.e. `setTimeout`). So it is not instantaneous at by any means.

Looking at the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bd984f0ee2cf40107a669d80d92566b8625b1e6b/src/core/ready.js) you see they actually set a timer for the callbacks:

```
// Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
window.setTimeout( jQuery.ready );
```

I'm not *exactly* sure what they mean here (any idea) - but it explains the behavior. I could see it being helpful to avoid race conditions, and blocking the UI but 'delaying ready' is unclear to me.

Comment: The `setTimeout()` is a workaround for IE9-10 firing off the `DOMContentLoaded` event before a listener is added for it. The code checks to see if `document.readyState` has already completed, then adds a `setTimeout()` to push the `jQuery.ready` callback to the event queue, giving time for the other queued async callbacks a chance to execute before `jQuery.ready` is executed.

Comment: but I'm using Chrome! the timing is probably negligible, but I'm trying to fire up a SignalR connection and need that done as soon as possible

Comment: Chrome properly handles it, it doesn't fire off the `DOMContentLoaded` event until it reaches the end of the `</body>` tag. IE9-10 does not, so it needs a workaround. The jQuery code checks for this in an if statement. It falls back to the proper behavior if the `document.readyState` is not ready.

Comment: yes it *works* but there is an unnecessary delay due to the timer. maybe there is some kind of race condition going on but I found it faster to put my SignalR initialization code in my own DOMContentLoaded as I only need to support modern browsers

Comment: That's likely due to the parsing of jQuery itself, which is 84KB.

Comment: Also, isn't it likely that using the devtools to monitor this slows it down as well?

Comment: @KyleBaker the Dev tools here was more to show that something happens in between. The window performance timing values wouldn't be affected by having tools turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Does anybody still use jQuery except me? ;)

As of **jQuery 3.0**, only the `$( handler )` syntax is recommended,
(which is equivalent to `$( document ).ready( handler )`).

From API docs: [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: This makes more to difficult to find where it is. I am handling a big Razor project with lots of occurrences of `$( document ).ready(handler)).` and if someone would change to this, every other dev on the team would complain...