# Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I get this error after a making trivial React example page:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Here's my code:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
'use strict';

var React = require('react');

var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <h1>Yo</h1>;
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<App />, document.body);
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What does this mean?

Comment: @go-oleg: This is ES6 short notation. It's not the issue because react-tools has ES6 transpiler. [See here](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html)

Comment: I ran into this same error, and as others have suggested, it's because your bundle.js file is loading too early. Move your <script> tag into the body (as the last line before the closing </body> tag) to resolve this error.

Comment: thats doesn't help here

Comment: @daslicht I hope you found your answer but just so it's said: DOUBLE CHECK that you're not mixing up classes and id's.  document.getElementById("foo") is never, ever, ever going to find a tag that reads <div class="foo">

Answer (score 639, accepted):

By the time script is executed, `document` element is not available yet, because `script` itself is in the `head`. While it's a valid solution to keep `script` in `head` and [render on `DOMContentLoaded` event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28965157/458193), it's even better to **put your `script` at the very bottom of the `body` *and* render root component to a `div` before it like this:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the `bundle.js`, call:

```
React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**You should always render to a nested `div` instead of `body`.** Otherwise, all sorts of third-party code (Google Font Loader, browser plugins, whatever) can modify the `body` DOM node when React doesn't expect it, and cause weird errors that are very hard to trace and debug. [Read more about this issue.](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375)

The nice thing about putting `script` at the bottom is that it won't block rendering until script load in case you add React server rendering to your project.

---

#### Update: (October 07, 2015 | [v0.14](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html))

> `React.render` is deprecated, use `ReactDOM.render`
> instead.

**Example:**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I'm using import statements in webpack and still get this error. I thought webpack will take care of the order of loading scripts no?

Comment: Consider to use defer 

<script defer src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.7.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.7.js"></script>
<!--your app code now-->
<script defer src="app.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: @thetrystero No, webpack has no knowledge about the relative place of your application’s bundle to the DOM nodes it operates on.

Comment: I also had to change mine from `document.getElementById('.root'));` to `document.getElementById('root'));` (got rid of the . )

Comment: Such cryptic error -- just putting script below root div made it work...

Comment: It's not the case of @DanAbramov but I received the same error by using a target container without a complete closing tag (for example <section id="" />)

Answer (score 53):

#### `/index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Application</title>
    <!-- load application bundle asynchronously -->
    <script async src="/app.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* pre-rendered critical path CSS (see isomorphic-style-loader) */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <!-- pre-rendered markup of your JavaScript app (see isomorphic apps) -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### `/app.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

function run() {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
}

const loadedStates = ['complete', 'loaded', 'interactive'];

if (loadedStates.includes(document.readyState) && document.body) {
  run();
} else {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run, false);
}
```

(IE9+)

**Note**: Having `<script async src="..."></script>` in the header ensures that the browser will start downloading JavaScript bundle *before* HTML content is loaded.

#### Source: [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/), [isomorphic-style-loader](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader)

Comment: It is `ReactDOM.render` instead of `React.render`.

Comment: Warning note: if you set your react to load asynchronously, it creates a race condition- if the browser finishes parsing the page before the JS is executed, you're fine. If the JS is loaded before the page is parsed, you will end up with the same issue the question is about. `defer` may be a better option

Answer (score 18):

the [ready function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) can be used like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  React.render(<App />, document.body);
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use the `onload` function:

```
<body onload="initReact()">...</body>
```

Comment: I think `DOMContentLoaded` would be more appropriate even to handle than `load` (this is what [jQuery uses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11523460/458193)). You can also do this in JS with `window.addEventListener`, no need for inline handlers and global functions.

Comment: Note, renderComponent will be depreciated. Use React.render() instead.

Comment: I'm using react-rails so moving script tag to bottom of body tag was not an option.  `$(document).ready` solved the problem.  Oh and yes use `render` instead of `renderComponent`.

Comment: It's extremely bad practice to use jQuery with React. Use either, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 12):

just a wild guess, how about adding to index.html the following:

```
type="javascript"
```

like this:

```
<script type="javascript" src="public/bundle.js"> </script>
```

For me it worked! :-)

Comment: Just FYI, this caused issues for me where as `type="text/javascript"` worked properly.

Comment: That is terrible that is actually fixed my issue. kind of sad, but not sure who to blame on this one, react or babel?

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same error. It turned out to be caused by a simple typo after changing my code from:

```
document.getElementById('root')
```

to

```
document.querySelector('root')
```

Notice the missing '#'
It should have been

```
document.querySelector('#root')
```

Just posting in case it helps anyone else solve this error.

Comment: I did not have a bundle.js call in my index.html page that I could move around to a new location. I was using Create-React-App, so this helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes,** basically what you done is right, except you forget that JavaScript is sync in many cases, so you running the code before your **DOM** gets loaded, there are few ways to solve this:

1) Check to see if **DOM** fully loaded, then do whatever you want, you can listen to **DOMContentLoaded** for example:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
</script>
```

2) Very common way is adding the script tag to the bottom of your `document` (after body tag):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

3) Using `window.onload`, which gets fired when the entire page loaded(img, etc)

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log("Everything is loaded");
});
```

4) Using `document.onload`, which gets fired when the **DOM** is ready:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log("DOM is ready");
});
```

There are even more options to check if **DOM** is ready, but the short answer is **DO NOT** run any script before you make sure your **DOM is ready** in every cases...

JavaScript is working along with **DOM** elements and if they are not available, will return **null**, could break the whole application... so always make sure you are fully ready to run your JavaScript before you do...

Answer (score 2):

If you use webpack for rendering your react and use HtmlWebpackPlugin in your react,this plugin builds its blank index.html by itself and injects js file in it,so it does not contain div element,as HtmlWebpackPlugin docs you can build your own index.html and give its address to this plugin,
in my webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [            
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'dev',
        template: 'dist/index.html'
    })
],
```

and this is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Epos report</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="app"></div>
   <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugin here if it's used to reference static HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error was caused by hot reloading, while introducing new classes. In that stage of the project, use normal watchers to compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

For those using ReactJS.Net and getting this error after a publish:

Check the properties of your .jsx files and make sure `Build Action` is set to `Content`. Those set to `None` will not be published. I came upon this solution from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002636/5793033).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar/same error message. In my case, I did not have the target DOM node which is to render the ReactJS component defined. Ensure the HTML target node is well defined with appropriate "id" or "name", along with other HTML attributes (suitable for your design need)

Comment: I had similar issue. In view I had <code>if</code> statement where expected target element should be generated if condition was met. In my case proper element wasn't render because of condition, but script executed and tried to mount component on element which didn't exist in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

When you got:

**Error: Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.**

You can use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event or move your `<script ...></script>` tag in the bottom of your body.

> The **DOMContentLoaded** event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easy just make basic HTML CSS js and **render the script from js**

```js
mport React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

var destination = document.querySelector('#container');

   ReactDOM.render(
<div>
<p> hello world</p>
</div>, destination


 );
```

```css
body{

    text-align: center;
    background-color: aqua;
  padding: 50px;
  border-color: aqua;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />   
    <title> app  </title>
  </head>
  <body>
 

    <div id="container">
      
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case of using jQuery - for some reason the `window.onload` doesn't act the same as jQuery's onload

So this one worked for me:

```
<script>
    $(function () {          <= replacing window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        ...

      window.ui = ui;
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, everything in the html file was set correctly (i.e. script was at the bottom of the body tag). The problem was solved by moving the definition of a component to a separate file from where the component was rendered to the ReactDOM.

So originally I had

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Comp extends React.Component {
    // component definition
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Comp />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Problem was solved after I moved the component definition to a separate file and imported

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Comp from './CompFile';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Comp />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case I did mistake something below in index.js and corrected.

**Error:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Solution:** `document.getElementById("root")`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root") // declared 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With webpack. there is a choice to load the html file with the htmlPlugin instead of us needing to define it. When this is the case, Webpack *is* going to create an html file that has the script tag over *above* the root-div element. One quick fix would be to add a new div to the dom dynamically and then write your react dom to it. This can be done on your reactDom render function defined (usually) on the index.js file as below.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
      <Router>
          <App />
      </Router>,
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
    );
```