# How To Use ReactJS in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, reactjs

I am having trouble using ReactJs in a Wordpress plugin.

I am developing a Wordpress plugin using ReactJs. Googling only found ReactJs in a Wordpress theme, not plugin development.

Comment: I was able to use shortcode with the PHP-based of my plugin.  Not sure how shortcode would work with React-based plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working on a plugin admin page.

Started with a working PHP-based plugin setting page.
Then replaced all PHP code in the setting UI page with

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Pre-transformed the JSX. I wasn't able to get JSX transform to work on the fly.  I am not if this possible in Wordpress.

Also ran into document not ready issue.  This was solved by this question.

[Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566317/invariant-violation-registercomponent-target-container-is-not-a-dom-elem)

Comment: I get the same error when I don't use Babel. If I include Babel, this error disappears and everything is back to normal. So, this can work if you include 3 scripts, React, ReactDOM and Babel and use "text/babel" for your app.js. Without Babel it doesn't work and I'm still trying to figure it out.