# React not rendering on Webpack Dev server

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I had this working, can't remember what I changed and now the page loads but no react is rendered onto the screen.  Not sure where the error is. No errors occur when I run webpack -m followed by npm start

webapp folder is like this...

- {app}
  -- App.js
- {public}
  -- bundle.js
  -- index.html
- webpack.config.js
- .babelrc
- package.json

here are the important files

webpack

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/App.js',
  output: {
    path: './public',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
      inline:true,
      contentBase: './public',
      port: 3333
    },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "newaccount",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a form submission for new accounts",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "---",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
          "es2015",
          "react"
    ]
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



class Testing extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>JUST A TEST</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Testing />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I have ever tried making the Component Testing an ES6 const like...

```
const Testing = () => return <div><h3>JUST A TEST</h3></div>
```

and still can't get anything to show up on the localhost:3333 or the full path from my computer.

Thanks for any help

Comment: no errors in the browser console?

Comment: nope no errors in the console :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get your example to run by doing three things.

First, add an `HTMLWebpackConfiguration` at the top of `webpack.config.js`.  Then, add an `index.html` page in `/app`.  Finally, make sure the configuration is pointed to the HTML file.  The final `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/app/App.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
      inline:true,
      contentBase: './public',
      port: 3333
    },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `app/index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</html>
```

Sources of info:

https://tylermcginnis.com/react-js-tutorial-1-5-utilizing-webpack-and-babel-to-build-a-react-js-app-5f804d729d3b#.f4sslv7ub

[Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566317/invariant-violation-registercomponent-target-container-is-not-a-dom-elem)

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/07/webpack-html-plugin/

Comment: Yeah I've actually made that example from that tutorial - was extremely helpful.  I was hoping to find a way to get my localhost running without html-webpack mod.

Comment: I think that the only way that it works is if you have an HTML file somewhere to "kick off" your bundle.  But if you find any other solution, please post it - I'd like to know too!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. You might want to revisit this solution.

After checking the `webpack-dev-server` documentation, I realized I needed to specify the devServer collection of properties in webpack config.  You have already done this in your example, which was 7 months prior to my reply.  Example from their docs:

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  compress: true,
  port: 9000
}
```

This resolved my case where index.html was not even loaded (per the browser network debug list).

I did not need to add `HTMLWebpackConfiguration` anywhere.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/