# Meteor-React Error: Target Container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm doing [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3ZGcBLBNVE&list=PLLnpHn493BHGGHRmdXip3GswwLWY9S6of&index=4) on Meteor1.4 with React and i'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.(…)

I have looked at [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566317/invariant-violation-registercomponent-target-container-is-not-a-dom-elem), but this being Meteor i can't tell why it's happening.

**main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>React Meteor Voting</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
});

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MeteorReact1.4",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "6.18.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Meteor startup's render method you are getting the element by id wherein in your html file, no such element exists. **Replace class with id** in the div in your html file's body

Comment: Awww you are so right. I created the div using emmet `.render-target` and then i could not see my stupid mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Swapnil,
I am using the same code, the same example and also using ID, not class. But in my case, it is showing a blank page. I checked the source code from the browser and the head code is reflected there but not the body part.
Any suggestion will be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: or use `querySelector()` instead and then you don't have to worry about by Id or Class.