# reactjs Target container is not a DOM element error

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactjs and react GA for google analytic integration i have the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
at invariant (bundle.js:2844)
at Object._renderNewRootComponent (bundle.js:41047)
at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (bundle.js:41137)
at Object.renderSubtreeIntoContainer [as unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer] (bundle.js:41079)
at OverlayTrigger.renderOverlay (bundle.js:85430)
at OverlayTrigger.componentDidUpdate (bundle.js:85319)
at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:90119)
at bundle.js:90773
at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (bundle.js:39950)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (bundle.js:95219)
```

I am trying to resolve the issue using several resources.But i couldn't find a solution.

**Code:**
Videoplayer.jsx

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import {Image, Modal} from 'react-bootstrap/lib';
import 'videojs-contrib-hls';
import GA from '../GA.jsx';

const liveVideoUrl = 'http://vid-129002.hls.chinanetcenter.broadcastapp.agoraio.cn/live/';
class VideoPlayer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
        this.state = {showPopup: false};        
        this.broadcastData = this.props.broadcastData;
        this.videoUrl = this.broadcastData.recordedUrl;
        this.videoType = 'video/mp4';
        let videoStreamName = this.broadcastData.streamId;
        this.live = null;

        if (this.broadcastData.status !== 'RECORDED') {
            this.videoUrl = liveVideoUrl + videoStreamName + '/playlist.m3u8';
            this.live = (<Image className="live-logo" src="/images/svg/live.svg"/>);
            this.videoType = 'application/x-mpegURL';
        }
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        const
            self = this,
            options = {
                autoplay: true,
                controls: true,
                preload: "auto",
                hls: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            };

        const playerTarget = 'play_video';
        this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, options);
        this.player.src({
          src: this.videoUrl,
          type: this.videoType,
        });
        this.player.on('ended', () => {
            self.setState({showPopup: true});
        });



        if (this.player.play()) {
            GA.ManualGA(playerTarget);
        }

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.player && this.player.dispose();
        this.player = null;
    }

    hideModal() {
        this.setState({showPopup: false});
    }

    render() {
        let screenShotUrl = this.broadcastData.screenShotUrl;
        let downloadLinkNode = [];

        if (screenShotUrl == null) {
            screenShotUrl = '/images/default-screenshot.png'
        }

        const style = {
            "backgroundImage": "url(" + screenShotUrl + ")"
        };

        if (this.showBanner) {
            if (this.isIphone) {
                downloadLinkNode.push(<Link key="appStore" className="btn btn-default btn-home-bg-one" target="_blank" to={"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/speakerswire/id100000?mt=8"}>
                    <Image src="/images/appstore.png" alt="google play" data-ga="app_dld_aftervideo_ios_click" /></Link>);
            } else {
                downloadLinkNode.push(<Link key="playStore" className="btn btn-default btn-home-bg-two" target="_blank" to={"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kryptolabs.android.speakerswire&hl=en"}>
                    <Image src="/images/playstore.png" alt="google play" data-ga="app_dld_aftervideo_android_click"/></Link>);
            }
        } else {
            downloadLinkNode.push(<Link key="appStore" className="btn btn-default btn-home-bg-one" target="_blank" to={"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/speakerswire/id100000?mt=8"}>
                    <Image src="/images/appstore.png" alt="google play" data-ga="app_dld_aftervideo_ios_click"/>
                </Link>
            );
            downloadLinkNode.push(<Link key="playStore" className="btn btn-default btn-home-bg-two" target="_blank" to={"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kryptolabs.android.speakerswire&hl=en"}>
                    <Image src="/images/playstore.png" alt="google play" data-ga="app_dld_aftervideo_android_click"/>
                </Link>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="blur-bg" style={style}/>
                <video className="video-js vjs-sublime-skin vjs-big-play-centered" data-setup='{ "inactivityTimeout": 0 }' ref={ r => { this.videoNode = r; } }/>
                {this.live}
                <Modal show={this.state.showPopup} dialogClassName="app-download-play-end" onHide={this.hideModal}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton />
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Image src="/images/swoo-logo-popup.svg" className="logo"/><br/>
                        <Image src="/images/svg/logo_black.svg"/>
                        <div className="title">To view more broadcasts, install SWOO app</div>
                        <h5>Get the App</h5>
                        {downloadLinkNode}
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default VideoPlayer
```

**GA.JSX**

```
    function GA(ReactGA) {
    const objects = ['channel_click', 'channel_home_click', 'share_btn_click', 'share_btn_click', 'terms_cond_click', 'privacy_policy_click', 'discover_btn_click', 'profile_btn_click', 'app_dld_close_btn_click', 'top_broadcaster_click', 'app_dld_andoid_btn_click', 'broadcast_live_click', 'broadcast_recorded_click',
     'app_dld_ios_btn_click', 'app_dld_ios_homebtn_click', 'app_dld_andoid_homebtn_click', 'app_dld_aftervideo_android_click', 'app_dld_aftervideo_ios_click', 'play_video', 'pause_video'];

        ReactGA.initialize('UA-96792697-3');''
        document.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
            let target = e.target.getAttribute('data-ga');
            let additional_value = e.target.getAttribute('data-value');

            if (objects.indexOf(target) >= 0) {
                ReactGA.event({category:'swoo', action: target});
            }

        });

         function ManualGA(target) {
                    ReactGA.event({category:'swoo', action: target});
        }
 }

export default GA;
```

**Index.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory, Redirect} from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Layout from './components/layout/layout.jsx';
import HomePageContainer from './containers/homePageContainer.jsx';
import SearchPageContainer from './containers/searchPageContainer.jsx';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore.jsx';
import BroadcastDetailContainer from './containers/broadcastDetailContainer.jsx';
import GA from './components/GA.jsx';
//import ManualGA from './components/GA.jsx';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
/////////-- Static Pages --///////////
import PrivacyPolicyContainer from './containers/privacyPolicyContainer.jsx';
import PrivacyPolicyforwebContainer from './containers/privacyPolicyforwebContainer.jsx';
import TermsofServiceContainer from './containers/termsOfService.jsx';
import TermsofServiceforwebContainer from './containers/termsofServiceforwebContainer.jsx';
import NotFoundPage from './containers/notFoundPage.jsx';

require("./stylesheets/customResponsive.css");
require("./stylesheets/customStyle.css");
require("./stylesheets/videojs.css");

ReactGA.initialize('UA-96791297-3');
GA(ReactGA);
//ManualGA(ReactGA);


/////////-- End Static Pages --///////////

const store = configureStore();

function fireTracking() {
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);
}

render
(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router onUpdate={fireTracking} history={browserHistory}>
            <Route component={Layout}>
                <Redirect from='/' to='/home'/>
                <Route path="/home" component={HomePageContainer}/>
                <Route path="/search" component={SearchPageContainer}/>
                <Route path="/broadcast/:broadcastId" component={BroadcastDetailContainer}/>
                <Route path={"/privacy-policy"} component={PrivacyPolicyContainer}/>
                <Route path={"/privacy"} component={PrivacyPolicyforwebContainer}/>
                <Route path={"/terms-of-service"} component={TermsofServiceContainer}/>
                <Route path={"/tos"} component={TermsofServiceforwebContainer}/>
                <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

In `videoPlayer.jsx` I am getting the abbove error at

```
if (this.player.play()) {
  GA.ManualGA(playerTarget);
}
```

Comment: have you defined the `id='container'` with any `div` in index.html file ? if not then use this `<div id='container'></div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invariant Violation: \_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566317/invariant-violation-registercomponent-target-container-is-not-a-dom-elem)

Comment: I hav ethe following code in index.html <!--Container for React rendering-->
<div id="container"></div>