# React.js Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dom, components

Hi I am getting this error:

`main.js:808 Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

I have visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566317/invariant-violation-registercomponent-target-container-is-not-a-dom-elem), but I cannot figure out what is wrong with what I am doing.

Here is the code I have right now:

`routes.js`:

```
export default (  
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
  </Route>
);
```

`app.js`

```
const store = configureStore();

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

`homepage.js`

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        Hello
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

I think that I am missing something easy but I am not sure what it is.  I have tried modifying my code to match the answers of that other question but it didnt work out.  Thank you for any help

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are trying to render you component App.js within HomePage, in that case, you are doing it wrongly. The TargetDOM element must be within HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `document.getElementById('app')` operation didn't find any corresponded html node in the page document. You have to create a `<div id="app"></div>` directly in your `index.html` so `document.getElementById('app')` could find it. Your `<div id="app">` in `HomePage` container is useless as it's unavailable in DOM during React app initialization.

Also, be sure to inject your `<script>` with bundled React app **after** `<div id="app"></div>` (inject that `<script>` to the end of the `body` tag to be safe).