# ASP.Net Core: Setting up React.js + webpack + babel in VS2017

Tags: c#, reactjs, webpack, asp.net-core

After some playing around with `ReactJS` (which was running on `webpack-server`), decided to try `ASP.Net Core` project in Visual Studio 2017.

1. I created empty `ASP.Net Core` project.
2. Removed all stuff in
       `wwwroot` and stuff related to `bower`.
3. Removed all controllers
       except `Home` and removed views except `Home/Index.cshtml`
4. Added
       `webpack.config.js`, `package.json` and `.babelrc`
5. Installed `Asp.React` from `Nuget`

My `package`:

```
{
  "name": "TrainDiary",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [
      "build"
    ]
  }
}
```

My `webpack config`:

```
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
let path = require('path');
const bundleFolder = "wwwroot/build/";
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        template:  path.resolve(__dirname,  'Scripts/app/index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Scripts/app/Core/app.js'), 
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    output:{
        filename: 'index.js',
        path:  path.resolve(__dirname, bundleFolder)
    },
    stats: {
            colors: true,
            modules: true,
            reasons: true,
            errorDetails: true
    },
    plugins: [ new CleanWebpackPlugin([bundleFolder]), HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]     
};
```

`babelrc` is simple like that `{ presets:['react'] }`

So, when I run `npm run build` everything is fine, in `wwwroot` it generates `index.js` and `index.html` as well.

But nothing happens when I run my application! I mean nothing at all. Blank white page. No error in console. Just like that.

Also, here is my `Startup.cs`:

```
namespace TrainDiary.Web
{
    using React.AspNet;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddReact();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseReact(config =>
            { });
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

`HomeController`:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

`Home/Index.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Load all required scripts (React + the site's scripts) -->
    @Html.Partial("~/wwwroot/build/index.html")
</body>
</html>
```

How come? What's wrong with this approach?

*UPD*:

entrance point `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app/Core/app.js'

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("content")
);
```

`Core/app.js` is here

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
               Hello, React!
           </div>
       )
    }
}
```

`index.html` which we try to render in `Index.cshtml`

```
<body>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Screenshot of the rendered stuff:

[image]

*UPD2*:

As Jose advised - changed `Index.cshtml` like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <script src="~/build/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Load all required scripts (React + the site's scripts) -->

    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and removed `webpack-html-plugin`.

Thats what I got now (`css-loader` worked btw):

[image]

*UPD3*:

Fixed some wrong stuff in `webpack.config` (entry point), but still no success:

```
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
let path = require('path');
const bundleFolder = "wwwroot/build/";


module.exports = {
    entry:'./Scripts/index.js', 
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    output:{
        filename: 'index.js',
        path:  path.resolve(__dirname, bundleFolder)
    },
    stats: {
            colors: true,
            modules: true,
            reasons: true,
            errorDetails: true
    },
    plugins: [ new CleanWebpackPlugin([bundleFolder])]     
};
```

*UPD4*:

Now it works! In previous case I just didn't pay attention to debugger console with error like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566317/invariant-violation-registercomponent-target-container-is-not-a-dom-elem).

So I changed `Index.cshtml` like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Load all required scripts (React + the site's scripts) -->
    <div id='content'></div>
    <script src="~/build/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And now it's fine!

[image]

Comment: could you please share your react app code ? maybe you should include <div> where react is adding all the app ?

Comment: Sure! Will share when I will be at home

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora sorry, yesterday didn't manage to get home haha

Comment: If you inspect the source code of your empty page. Could you see the div id = content?

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora hmm, looks like nope

Comment: You are having two title sections in your html. I think that because the partial view in your mvc view is loading a full template by using html wepack plugin

Comment: Try to set up your view with static link to the bundle js. And remove the html webpack plugin and give a go..

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora ok, I'll try now

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora thx, but didn't helped. Link is fine, `div` with `id = 'content'` is there but thats it. Look at my UPD2

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora finally I maked it working!

Comment: glad it works now ! :)

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora could you put up your advises in answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of comments' suggestions:

- Make sure  is being render in your app code
- Remove HTMLWebpackPlugin and change Index.cshtml to include bundle.js ( the partial view in your mvc view is loading a full template by using html wepack plugin)

Glad to help you!