# Jest Testing Error - Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, chai, enzyme

I'm new to doing unit testing and I keep getting this error:

> Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
>
> at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
>
> at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17238:34)
>
> at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17317:12)
>
> at Object. (src/client/index.js:243:73)
>
> at Object. (src/client/components/block/Header.js:294:40)
>
> at Object. (src/client/components/block/index.js:123:41)
>
> at Object. (src/client/containers/app.js:195:40)
>
> at Object. (tests/client/containers/App.test.js:13:12)

I think it has to do with the way my app.js is structured but dont know why...

Here my App.js :

```
const App = () => (
  <Box>
    <Router getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation} hashType={'noslash'} basename={'/'}>
      <Box>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/:room" component={Room}/>
      </Box>
    </Router>
  </Box>
)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    message: state.message
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App)
```

I'm using jest/enzyme/chai for unit tests

my App.test.js :

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import App from '../../../src/client/containers/app'

jest.mock('react-router')

describe('<App />', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <App/>
    ).dive()
  })
})
```

my devDependecies in package.json :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-__coverage__": "^0.111111.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-watch": "^2.0.2",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-enzyme": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "chai-jest-diff": "^1.0.2",
    "chai-jest-snapshot": "^2.0.0",
    "dirty-chai": "^2.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "nyc": "^6.4.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  },
```

and my webpack.config.js :

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.js',

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },

  watchOptions: {
    poll: 1000,
    aggregateTimeout:300,
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query:{
        presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

Thank you for help :)

EDIT:

Looking for a solution, I noticed that the error occurs during the import of my components! Would it come from webpack?

EDIT:

My error was in my HEADER.JS because I use persistor for manage my user connection.
For moment I delete it

Comment: Maybe need more details? What is my error? Ty :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to ensure that your element with the `id="root"` in your `index.html` file is not set on on the `body` element. Reason being that by the time the script finishes execution, `document` element is not available yet.

Refer to this answer by @Dan Abramov [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566317/invariant-violation-registercomponent-target-container-is-not-a-dom-elem).