# simple javascript works in intel xdk emulator but not on device

Tags: javascript, testing, emulation, intel-xdk

I'm trying to test my javascript alerts and such on my iphone and they won't work. They do however work on the emulator. What's the problem? I have very very simple javascript. I've included a screenshot. It's an event_listener and a click counter. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `textContent` instead of `innerText`.
You can find difference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Same deal. Works in emulator. Not on device.

Comment: Why do you use 'var document;' ?

Comment: The Intel xdk code editor will give me an error if I don't. Every dom object you use there has to be declared first. If I do window.alert I will have to declare    "var window"  first, etc.

Comment: Regarding those "errors" in the edit window, especially the one for alert(), see this reply to your related post > http://stackoverflow.com/a/34845771/2914328