# How to create a console like in IRC in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new all around HTML and JavaScript. Now I am trying to build a simple program that get input from the command line by the user and print it on the big console window. Now when I insert a simple text it does not print nothing into the box. Is there a special object should I use?

this is my code:

```
</head>

<body>
<img src="img/Mellanox_logo.jpg" alt="logo" align="middle">
<h1>Menu</h1>
<div id="container1" >
    <div id="console" >
        <p>
            <script>
                function showVal(){
                    var tmp = document.lineform.command_line.value;
                    document.getElementsByName('command_line').value = tmp;
                }
            </script>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div >
        <form id="form1" name="lineform"  >
            <input id="commandline"  type="text" name="command_line" placeholder="Command line" onclick="showVal()"   >
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the css:

```
    h1{
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
}
p{
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#container1{
    width:1300px ;
}
#form1{
    width:1300px ;
}
#console{
    border:5px solid dodgerblue;
    background-color: white;
    height: 650px ;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
}
  #commandline{
      width: inherit;
      border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
      height: 30px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      font-size: 18px;
      position: absolute;
  }
```

this is how the command line and the window looks like:
[image]

Comment: Does the console show any errors? Has the `DOM` loaded correctly before you start manipulating it?

Comment: Why do you want to reassign the same value for  `command_line` ? Use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get an element by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- For this case i think you should be using getElementById instead of getElementsByName.

2.- I'd recommend not using a form, but instead have the input in the div's "root".

3.- A text input doesnt have a onclick (or at least it doesn't do what you want it to do)

4.- Add a button type input that executes the code through `onclick="blabla();"`

5.- i'd recommend putting your script at the end of the page since it works with the DOM and you're not using JQuery.

6.- add an id to the `<p>` element inside of the console `<div>`

```
<body>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <div id="container1">
    <div id="console">
      <p id="console_content">

      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="commandline" type="text" name="command_line" placeholder="Command line">
      <input id="commandButton" type="button" name="command_button" value="confirm" onclick="showVal();">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

7.- new script:

```
<script>
  function showVal() {
    var tmp = document.getElementById("commandline").value;
    document.getElementById('console_content').innerHTML += (tmp + "<br/>");
  }
</script>
```

Here's a JFiddle so you can see it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/bLehLrum/

Comment: There is [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) for JavaScript which is [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523359/is-domcontentloaded-event-exactly-the-same-as-jquerys-ready-function) to jQuery `ready`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), you need to the following:

Change,

```
document.getElementsByName('command_line').value = tmp;
```

To

```
document.getElementsByName('command_line')[0].value = tmp;
```

This gets the first element in the array, notice how there is an ***s*** at the end of *getElements* which suggests plural. This should help you in the future.

**Reading Material**

[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Comment: still i dont see nothing in the window

Answer (score 0):

Exdending [Script47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3554833/script47) answer, The problem is you are **taking the value from input field and setting the same value again to it**, That's why you are seeing any change/affect.

Answer (score 0):

If by `the box` you mean the console, you should change your function with this

```
function showVal(){
    // get the value of the input
    var tmp = document.getElementById('commandline').value;

    // add to the innerHTML of the console the tmp value
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "<p>"+tmp+"</p>";
}
```

[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Your code try to reassign the value of `command_line` with the same value.
`document.lineform.command_line.value` could be the same as `document.getElementsByName('command_line')[0]`

Comment: still the same. look at the image that i uploaded